# Getting Bitcoin address from Android Bitcoin wallets

Tags: wallet, android

In the android app that I am developing, I need to send a request to check if other Bitcoin apps exist on the user’s phone, and if that is the case, I need to get the user’s Bitcoin address from the wallet. 
Is there any type of API/URI specified for this? Or how else can I do that?